# Using miceforest for imputation and getting an error on RandomState.choice()

Tags: python, imputation

I'm working with a Kaggle dataset playing with different imputation techniques, and I'm getting an error from the miceforest package that I don't understand.

Full Colab [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TjSAPvB9Z3rsWUlh17qD96jlNRsoPCxv?usp=sharing), but the gist is that the data I'm using are the numeric features from my X_train dataset.

```
X = df_agg.drop(['TARGET','SK_ID_CURR'], axis = 1)
y = df_agg.TARGET

X_train_raw, X_test_raw, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
  X, y, test_size=0.10, random_state=42, stratify=y)


X_train_raw, X_dev_raw, y_train, y_dev = train_test_split(
  X_train_raw, y_train,
  test_size=1/9.,
  random_state=42,
  stratify=y_train
)
num_features = X_train_raw.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'float64']).columns 



kernel = mf.MultipleImputedKernel(
  data=X_train_raw[num_features],
  save_all_iterations=True,
  random_state=1991
)
```

And here's the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-b6bd23e78d87> in <module>
      2   data=X_train_raw[num_features],
      3   save_all_iterations=True,
----> 4   random_state=1991
      5 )

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/miceforest/MultipleImputedKernel.py in __init__(self, data, datasets, variable_schema, mean_match_candidates, save_all_iterations, save_models, random_state)
     56                 save_all_iterations=save_all_iterations,
     57                 save_models=save_models,
---> 58                 random_state=random_state,
     59             )
     60         )

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/miceforest/KernelDataSet.py in __init__(self, data, variable_schema, mean_match_candidates, save_all_iterations, save_models, random_state)
     88             mean_match_candidates=mean_match_candidates,
     89             save_all_iterations=save_all_iterations,
---> 90             random_state=random_state,
     91         )
     92 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/miceforest/ImputedDataSet.py in __init__(self, data, variable_schema, mean_match_candidates, save_all_iterations, random_state)
     87             self.imputation_values[var] = {
     88                 0: self._random_state.choice(
---> 89                     data[var].dropna(), size=self.na_counts[var]
     90                 )
     91             }

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.choice()

ValueError: 'a' cannot be empty unless no samples are taken
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of this package - can you link me the kaggle data you are running this on? As a quick check - can you make sure that there isn't a column in data that has 100% missing values when you pass it to this function? This error occurs when you pass an empty object to numpy.random.choice(), so data[var].dropna() must be empty.

Comment: I've checked and it doesn't seem to have any empty features. The data can be found via the Kaggle [link] (https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-credit-default-risk/data). I've updated the linked Colab so it's easier to see what feature dev I've done and then the MICE error. Please let me know if troubleshooting live would be easier. Now I'm simply curious to see where I went wrong.